# Movie involving a teenage boy who goes back in time and saves a royal from drowning

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

In a movie I remember watching, a teenage boy went back in time too far (he wanted to go to his sports game he missed out on) and saves like a royal from drowning (I think), but needs to be sent pills to stay alive in that time.

He tries to travel back with his newfound love, but has to go back to get her as she missed the point (this was at the end of the movie).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, how did the boy travel through time? Your description makes it sound like he did so intentionally, so did he use a time machine of some sort? And did he travel back to medieval times? You mentioned a royal but weren't clear about what sort of time period he travelled back to.

Comment: Did he go back a few hours too far or a few centuries?

Comment: Which point did she miss? The point of the movie? Scoring a point in the game? The point of the pills?

Answer (score 6):

*Crusade in Jeans*, a 2006 Dutch movie.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusade_in_Jeans_(film)):

> Dolf is a 15-year-old **boy from Rotterdam who plays for the junior national football team. At the beginning of the film, Dolf and his team are playing an important championship game** against the Belgian team in the German city of Speyer. They were trailing by a goal, **and got the chance to equalise in the final minutes which Dolf blew.**
>
> Dolf's mother works in a research centre in Rotterdam where **a time machine has been developed.** It allows an object, animal or person to be moved to a specified time and place in the past, and to bring them back again. But, a person moving to the past can only return to the present by being at an exact location at an exact time. Furthermore, **a special medication is needed daily to stay alive in the past.**
>
> **Dolf decides to go back in time one day to replay the match** [...] in his haste he accidentally enters the password instead of the destination date, and **consequently travels to the year 1212.** He ends up at the location of the present-day football stadium, not far from the city of Speyer, which already existed then. [...]
>
> During the crusade, Dolf applies his modern-day knowledge to save the lives of many children, battling disease, kidnappers and hunger. **He even saves one of the leaders, Prince Carolus, from drowning.** [...]
>
> Although Dolf and Jenne succeed in getting to the location on time, a fight with the slave traders erupts and **Dolf is forced to leave Jenne behind in 1212 and return to the present alone.**
>
> Back home, Dolf manages to persuade his mother to let him go back to 1212 in order to get Jenne. His mother agrees and **Dolf leaves for 1212 once more, setting a new time and place for his return.**

---

Found with the query `Sci-Fi boy back in time sports princess` on [whatismymovie.com](https://whatismymovie.com/results?text=Sci-Fi+boy+back+in+time+sports+princess), filtered by "traditional search". I figured there being a royalty and a female love interest, `princess` might be a relevant keyword, but Jenne is actually not a princess and the movie also pops up in the results with replacing `princess` by `royalty`.